# `declare -F` does not work in zsh

Tags: zsh, function

`declare -f` Shows function definition in both bash & zsh.

```
$ declare -f
VCS_INFO_adjust () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
VCS_INFO_bydir_detect () {
    # undefined
    builtin autoload -XUz
}
VCS_INFO_check_com () {
    setopt localoptions NO_shwordsplit
    case $1 in
        (/*) [[ -x $1 ]] && return 0 ;;
        (*) (( ${+commands[$1]} )) && return 0 ;;
    esac
    return 1
}
....
```

`declare -F` show functions name is bash but not in zsh.

```
blueray@blueray-PC:~$ declare -F
declare -f __expand_tilde_by_ref
declare -f __get_cword_at_cursor_by_ref
declare -f __git_eread
declare -f __git_ps1
declare -f __git_ps1_colorize_gitstring
declare -f __git_ps1_show_upstream
declare -f __grub_dir
declare -f __grub_get_last_option
....
```

What might be the reason behind it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Zsh, [`declare -F` declares a double-precision floating point variable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset):

```
$ declare -F myvar
$ echo $myvar
0.0000000000
```

To list all function names in Zsh, use `typeset -f +`.

In `zsh`, the `$functions` special associative array maps function names to their definition so `${(k)functions}` which expands to the *keys* of that associative array will also expand to the list of function names.

Bash and Zsh are different shells, you can’t expect them to behave in exactly the same way.

Comment: When I write `declare -F` it is supposed to show all the function names. It does so in bash, as shown in my question.

Comment: It’s not “supposed to” do anything. In Bash, it shows all function names; in Zsh, it declares a floating-point variable.

Comment: What is the equivalent of `declare -F` in zsh.

Comment: `typeset -f +`.

Comment: `typeset -F` and floating point support was added to ksh in 1993. While bash added its `typeset -F` with a different meaning in 1996. `zsh` added floating point support (with `typeset -F`) in 1999. In 2020, bash still doesn't support floating point arithmetics.

Answer (score 2):

`declare` is a non-standard shell extension.

You cannot expect this to work the same in `bash` and `zsh`.

In general, if you like to use non-standard extensions in a shell script, make sure to use the shell they have been designed for with the behavior you expect. In other words: If you like to get `bash` behavior, use `bash` fr your script.

BTW: The feature you like to to use is not in `POSIX`